# Spreadsheet formula to list all unique entries EXCEPT for certain cells in a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Ok, so I have 3 columns that look roughly like this:

```
Name            Paid            To        
========        ========        ========
John            10              Roy
Jane            50              Roy
Mary            25              Trisha
John            30              Roy
Jane            15              Trisha
```

What's the formula to:

- List all unique values from the 'Name' Column,

  - which have a 'Paid' value greater than 29,
  - which were collected by 'Roy'

The expected result is a column which lists 'John' and 'Jane' once each.

On my own, I've only made it past the first requirement, using the UNIQUE() function, but I'm not sure how to add conditions. :(

Answer (score 0):

The following might do what you want (assuming the first "John" is in `A2` and the last Tricia is in `C6`):

- Enter 0 in `E1`
- Enter `=WENN(UND(C2="Roy";B2>29);1;0)+E1` in `E2` and pull this formula down to the other rows (sorry, my Excel speaks German, so that should likel be `IF` and `AND` and commas instead of semicola)
- Enter `=VERWEIS(ZEILE(E1)-1;E$1:E$99;A$2:A$100)` in `F1` and pull this formula down to the other rows (sorry, now I am at a loss: `ZEILE` is probably `ROW`, but I don't know what `VERWEIS` is, something like `LOOKUP`?)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a case for using advanced filter

Assuming the 'Name' column is in Cell A1,
define your criteria as follows:

1. have a 'Paid' value greater than 29 --> In cell F1, type 'Paid', in cell F2, type '>29' (without ')
2. were collected by 'Roy'--> Similarly, G1 = To, G2 = Roy

   - Then select all three columns of your data including the headers
   - Filter - Advanced
   - Copy to another location (or you could filter in place if you wish)
   - List Range: $A$1:$C$6
   - Criteria Range: $F$1:$G$2
   - Copy to: $I$1
   - Unique Records only